# How to add 60FPS Viewfinder Custom Camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession, avcapture

I’m having trouble making my iOS app with a custom camera run in 60FPS or above. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I tried setting it to 60 FPS but then the viewfinder went black. I also gave my code to ChatGPT and it could not figure it out.